# Modelica pipe model: hight vs length

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to model a tank-pipe system in Modelica. It is possible to set the "Static head (Height(port_b) - Height(port_a) of the pipe for example to -100m and the pipe lenght to 1m. This is not possible form a physical point of view right? Or am I missing something?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lars,

That's right. In reality the elevation of a pipe can't exceed it's length.

In practice, however, you can use an elevation longer than the pipe length if you need to "offset" the friction pressure drop, i.e. in case of fitting a model.

Another example could be a very long vertical pipe where frictional loss is negligible (large diameter or low flow velocity).

Regards,
Rene